# Filtering routes

Tags: routes

I'm using following code to route urls to specific template

```
'<restaurantSlug:{slug}>-nutrition' =>  ['template' => '_nutrition/restaurant'],
```

is there a way to limit slug results to specific channel otherwise I can add anything before -nutrition and it's getting routed as well. Which is not that clean and also don't allow me to use redirects (retour plugin) since the page don't actually throw 404 error.

Or any other approach that I've missed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app won't know about your Channels when it's checking static routes, without some trickery, or some *very* verbose auto-generated routes—at which point it seems like you might as well just use the built-in Element routing functionality. Can I ask why your *Nutrition* section can't just have a URI like `{slug}-nutrition` in the first place?

You *can*, however, perform this check once the request arrives at the template—something like this:

```
{# Set the additional `section` constraint when fetching the Entry! %}
{% set customRouteEntry = craft.entries({
  section: 'nutrition',
  slug: restaurantSlug
}).one() %}

{% if not customRouteEntry %}
  {% exit 404 %}
{% endif %}

<h1>{{ customRouteEntry.title }}</h1>
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. Well the restaurant' nutrition entries doesn't exist and generated on the fly by using entries fields. Complicated setup.